# Не пишутся и не читаются файлы из внутренней памяти на некоторых Android устройствах

Tags: android, unity3d, разработка-игр

Странная проблема. В настройках стоит Prefer External для установки, с пермишенами проблем нет и т.п.

Но на Lenovo A7600-H с Android 4.4.2 не получается записать/прочитать файл, используя `Application.persistentDataPath`.

Например,

```
var path = Application.persistentDataPath + "/save.sv"
File.WriteAllText(@path , str);
```

Ошибок никаких нет. Если после этого проверить существование файла, то `File.Exists(path)` вернёт `false`.

В какую сторону копать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем, не знаю, что там внутри `Application.persistentDataPath` и т.п. Решил явно путь до внутренней памяти брать:

```
public static string GetInternalStoragePath() {
    try {
        IntPtr obj_context = AndroidJNI.FindClass("android/content/ContextWrapper");
        IntPtr method_getFilesDir = AndroidJNIHelper.GetMethodID(obj_context, "getFilesDir", "()Ljava/io/File;");

        using (AndroidJavaClass cls_UnityPlayer = new AndroidJavaClass("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer")) {
            using (AndroidJavaObject obj_Activity = cls_UnityPlayer.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("currentActivity")) {
                IntPtr file = AndroidJNI.CallObjectMethod(obj_Activity.GetRawObject(), method_getFilesDir, new jvalue[0]);
                IntPtr obj_file = AndroidJNI.FindClass("java/io/File");
                IntPtr method_getAbsolutePath = AndroidJNIHelper.GetMethodID(obj_file, "getAbsolutePath", "()Ljava/lang/String;");

                var path = AndroidJNI.CallStringMethod(file, method_getAbsolutePath, new jvalue[0]);

                if (path != null) {
                    return path;
                }
                else {
                    return null;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e) {    
        return null;
    }
}
```