# Работа с внешним хранилищем в Unity под Android без использования нативных плагинов

Tags: android, unity3d, разработка-игр

Можно ли как-нибудь работать с внешним хранилищем в Android через unity без создания jar файлов?

Библиотечные функция `persistentDataPath` не работает. Я пытаюсь для примера просто создать папку. Проверяю на существование папки и если таковой нету то создаю. Но не на устройстве, не на sdcard не создается.

Кто решал эту проблему, соориентируйте пожалуйста, что делать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В Unity можно нативные вещи и без плагинов вызывать. У меня в проекте тоже проблема была с `persistentDataPath`: [Не пишутся и не читаются файлы из внутренней памяти на некоторых Android устройствах](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/827782/15479).

Вы можете в Unity, используя [`AndroidJavaObject`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AndroidJavaObject.html) и [`AndroidJavaClass`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AndroidJavaClass.html), сделать многие вещи специфичные для Android без использования плагинов.

К примеру, вот как я получал [`getFilesDir`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getFilesDir()) из Unity:

```
public static string GetInternalStoragePath() {
    try {
        IntPtr obj_context = AndroidJNI.FindClass("android/content/ContextWrapper");
        IntPtr method_getFilesDir = AndroidJNIHelper.GetMethodID(obj_context, "getFilesDir", "()Ljava/io/File;");

        using (AndroidJavaClass cls_UnityPlayer = new AndroidJavaClass("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer")) {
            using (AndroidJavaObject obj_Activity = cls_UnityPlayer.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("currentActivity")) {
                IntPtr file = AndroidJNI.CallObjectMethod(obj_Activity.GetRawObject(), method_getFilesDir, new jvalue[0]);
                IntPtr obj_file = AndroidJNI.FindClass("java/io/File");
                IntPtr method_getAbsolutePath = AndroidJNIHelper.GetMethodID(obj_file, "getAbsolutePath", "()Ljava/lang/String;");

                var path = AndroidJNI.CallStringMethod(file, method_getAbsolutePath, new jvalue[0]);

                if (path != null) {
                    return path;
                }
                else {
                    return null;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e) {    
        return null;
    }
}
```

По аналогии можете написать код для получения пути к внешнему хранилищу.

Comment: Эта функция возвращает ссылку на внутреннюю память? Или в папку с приложением Android/obb/com.Company.Application/files?

Comment: @GnomSkull `/data/data/{имя_пакета}/files`.